# how much concurrect connection using curl remote server with same server

Tags: php, curl

I want to upload file to remote server.multiple user upload the files at same time so any limitation of curl connection

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in limitation on the max amount of curl_easy handles you can have running concurrently, nor any max limit of curl handles in a curl_multi handle, curl could easily upload over 1000 files concurrently without problems. curl will be the last of your problems, most (all? probably) operating systems have a max number of open sockets/file handles per process, for example, [on windows server 2008, the limit seems to be somewhere around 16,000 handles per session](https://serverfault.com/a/249482/321694), and if those limitations doesn't bite you first, you'll probably run out of RAM long before you hit any limits of curl itself.